# how to automatically save changes to modx made through the database?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I added resources via phpmyadmin to the site_content table in database. These resources are displayed in the modx resource tree. But they don’'t have an alias. It appears automatically only after I click the "Save" button in modx
Is it possible to automate this process somehow?

Answer (score 0):

When resource creates via Manager it has proper alias(see `alias` and `uri` fields in `modx_site_content` table) + information in resource tree cache. Ho do you add them, manually? If so I may you suggest the next: add them all firstly via phpmyadmin and then open Manager and run "Regenerate URLs", this will rebuild all other what's necessary for proper addressing.

Alternatively you can add resources via MODX API, but some code will be needed and bulk data input.

Comment: Solved it this way: 1. Added resources via sql request in phpmyadmin. 2. «regenerate urls» 3. Opened “Console” and ran the code: <?php
$pages = $modx->getIterator('modResource', ['parent:IN' => [1212]]);

foreach ($pages as $p) {
  $title = $p->get('pagetitle');
  $alias = $p->get('alias'); 
  $alias = $p->cleanAlias($title);
  $p->set('alias', $alias);
  $p->save();
}.              P.S. sorry, can’t find a way of presenting the code in the usual way in comments

Comment: yes, this is what I meant said "via API" - using cleanAlias() method. Good you've solved that!